# Render 360 video from gameplay in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-virtual-reality

I want to render a 360 video from my game in Unity 5 that look like "WARCRAFT: SKIES OF AZEROTH" on Youtube. Can you please tell me how can I make a video like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using this plugin: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29704 with this other plugin: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032
With the two together you can render 360 videos for vr, or whatever you want.